# How to specify the file encoding in IntelliJ's command line formatter

Tags: intellij-idea, encoding

After running [IntelliJ's command line code formatter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-formatter.html%20IntelliJ's%20command%20line%20code%20formatter) on a set of Java source files the German characters in the source are replaced with "garbage".

How can I configure the input and output encoding of the formatter?

I tried adding `-encoding iso-8859-15 -docencoding iso-8859-15` as an option to the formatter command line but those options are not recognized.

I also tried creating an idea.properties file with the following content:

```
-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-15
```

And running the formatter with the environment variable `IDEA_PROPERTIES` set pointing to this file:

```
C:\>set IDEA_PROPERTIES="E:\project\config-files\idea.properties"
```

I also tried inserting the option `-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-15` directly in the idea.bat file (which is called by the format.bat.

None of these worked.

How can I ensure that the formatter respects the encoding of these source files?

Command line used now is like

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.4\bin\format.bat" -r E:\project\java style -m *.java -s e:\project\config-files\CodeStyleSettings.xml
```

Note: If I convert the source file to UTF-8 before running the formatter the formatting works as expected (the German characters are preserved).

Another note: If the format code is run within the IDE GUI it is possible to set the file encoding in the project options.  The command line formatter does not make use of a project so these settings are not respected.

The goal is to turn this into a step in our automated process that can be run by any of a number of users. So I'd like to avoid changes to config files in a user's specific directory like the [IDE configuration directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519).

Comment: See [Configuring JVM options and platform properties](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869) about how to specify custom VM options for IDE process. Also try to specify default IDE and project encoding in File | Other Settings... | Settings for New Projects | Editor | **File Encodings**.

Comment: @Andrey Thanks for the tip. I tried adding the `-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-15` option to the idea64.exe.vmoptions file but that has no effect. I also tried adding the `-encoding iso-8859-15 -docencoding iso-8859-15` options but that crashes the tool because it does not know these options. I added some notes to explain why changing user specific config files or setting in a project are not a solution in our case.